# How to remove default target group creation in elastic Beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

I have the following ebexensions settings for a test environment, where I'm trying to setup an https-only service (my ELB is https only, my EC2 machines are port-80 only):

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:
   LoadBalancerType: application

aws:elbv2:listener:443:
   DefaultProcess: https
   ListenerEnabled: 'true'
   Protocol: HTTPS
   SSLCertificateArns: xxxx

aws:elbv2:listener:default:
   ListenerEnabled: 'false'
```

When I run `eb create MyEnv1`, the environment gets created with an ELB that has one listener for HTTPS (as expected) but with TWO target groups, both pointing to the same instances:

```
awseb-AWSEB-ABCDEFG1234
awseb-https-HIJKLMN5678
```

The ELB only uses the second target group (xxx-https-xxx).
How do I avoid creation of the first one? I don't need it.
thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution! I simply use 'default' process instead of 'https':

```
aws:elbv2:listener:443:
    DefaultProcess: default <=======

aws:elbv2:listener:default: <=======
    ListenerEnabled: 'false'
```